Excel / MS GraphAPI | Could not obtain a WAC access token
Building a small MS Graph script that updates a field within an Excel Sheet stored within OneDrive.
As shown in the code below, it's updating field A1 with '200'.
This is very much a WIP and will be updated to other things down the line.
Code:
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication
import requests

def get_access_token(client_id, tenant_id, client_secret):
    """
    Authenticate and obtain an access token using MSAL for a confidential client.
    """
    authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
    app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
        client_id,
        authority=authority,
        client_credential=client_secret
    )
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])
    if "access_token" in result:
        return result['access_token']
    else:
        raise Exception("Failed to acquire access token: " + result.get("error_description", ""))

def create_session(access_token, user_id, file_id):
    """
    Create a session for an Excel file to make changes that persist on a specified user's OneDrive.
    """
    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/drive/items/{file_id}/workbook/createSession"
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}", "Content-Type": "application/json"}
    data = {"persistChanges": True}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()['id']
    else:
        raise Exception("Failed to create session: " + response.text)

def update_cell(access_token, user_id, file_id, session_id, sheet_name, cell_address, value):
    """
    Update a specific cell in the Excel sheet using a session on a specified user's OneDrive.
    """
    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/drive/items/{file_id}/workbook/worksheets/{sheet_name}/range(address='{cell_address}')"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "workbook-session-id": session_id
    }
    data = {"values": [[value]]}
    response = requests.patch(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    if response.status_code != 204:
        raise Exception("Failed to update cell: " + response.text)

def close_session(access_token, user_id, file_id, session_id):
    """
    Close the session after modifications are made to ensure changes persist on a specified user's OneDrive.
    """
    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/drive/items/{file_id}/workbook/closeSession"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "workbook-session-id": session_id
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code != 204:
        raise Exception("Failed to close session: " + response.text)

def main():
    """
    Main function to execute the process.
    """
    CLIENT_ID = 'REMOVED'
    TENANT_ID = 'REMOVED'
    CLIENT_SECRET = 'REMOVED'
    USER_ID = 'REMOVED'
    FILE_ID = 'REMOVED'  # Directly use the known file ID
    SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1'
    CELL_ADDRESS = 'A1'
    NEW_VALUE = '200'

    try:
        access_token = get_access_token(CLIENT_ID, TENANT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
        session_id = create_session(access_token, USER_ID, FILE_ID)
        update_cell(access_token, USER_ID, FILE_ID, session_id, SHEET_NAME, CELL_ADDRESS, NEW_VALUE)
        print("Cell updated successfully!")
        close_session(access_token, USER_ID, FILE_ID, session_id)
        print("Session closed successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Error I'm getting is:

Failed to create session: {"error":{"code":"AccessDenied","message":"Could not obtain a WAC access token.","innerError":{"date":"2024-05-11T13:23:08","request-id":"89fd141b-9888-4a5d-9aa6-3951878c1c45","client-request-id":"89fd141b-9888-4a5d-9aa6-3951878c1c45"}}}

Kind of hitting a roadblock currently.
Any help would be appreciated immensely!
The aim is to be able to authenticate, find a file & update the data in a cell.
All of the above are dynamically changed via variables (see code).
I've checked permissions surrounding this and Microsoft Graph is both able to access (Read) User's Info & User's OneDrive. I've been using Graph Explorer to check (and Grant Admin Approval to) permissions.
App Reg > App Name > API Perms


What are the file extensions for Excel files, such as .xlsx or .xltm?
If the file is not in .xlsx format, consider converting it to .xlsx & using an above API
